# Splitting a non delimited column and create an additional column to count which number value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem in which I want to take Table 1 and turn it into Table 2 using Python.

Does anybody have any ideas? I've tried to split the Value column from table 1 but run into issues in that each value is a different length, hence I can't always define how much to split it.

Equally I have not been able to think through how to create a new column that counts the position that value was in the string.

Table 1, before:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 000000S |
| 2 | 000FY |

Table 2, after:

| ID | Position | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | 7 | S |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | F |
| 2 | 5 | Y |

Answer (score 1):

You can  split the string to individual characters and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
out = (df
  .assign(Value=df['Value'].apply(list))
  .explode('Value')
)
```

output:

```
   ID Value
0   1     0
0   1     0
0   1     0
0   1     0
0   1     0
0   1     0
0   1     S
1   2     0
1   2     0
1   2     0
1   2     F
1   2     Y
```

Comment: Thank you! With the answer below that gets me what I need, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
   ID    Value
0   1  000000S
1   2    000FY
```

Doing:

```
df.Value = df.Value.apply(list)
df = df.explode('Value')
df['Position'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   ID Value  Position
0   1     0         1
0   1     0         2
0   1     0         3
0   1     0         4
0   1     0         5
0   1     0         6
0   1     S         7
1   2     0         1
1   2     0         2
1   2     0         3
1   2     F         4
1   2     Y         5
```

Comment: great minds… :p +1 (23 more to go to 10k!)